# Powershell Select-String -ExactMatch?

Tags: powershell

Im trying to find a way using Select-String and search for exact match in a file, and get all the lines that contains this exact match in exact colum.
Example Snippet from data file:

```
08/25/2021 11:56:03 muzi.puzi 123 Bla
08/25/2021 19:56:03 bla.bla 1234 Bla
08/25/2021 19:56:03 abc.def 54 bla123
```

```
Function Get_User_Dates_From_DBFile ([int] $Num, [string] $Db_File){
    #Rereive all the dates in DataFile BiometricNum has signed on or off
    $Dates = gc $Db_File | Select-String -Pattern "^$BioMetric_Num" 
    Return ($Date | Sort | Get-Unique) 
}

Get_User_Dates_From_DBFile 123 $Db_file
```

This will give me all Three lines, I want to make sure that it doesnt catch anything more than that (Example 1234) and also make sure it doesnt catch 123 at the end of the last line, as the nubers is refering only to the 4th colounm

Any Advice would be great, Thanks

Comment: Define: "*exact match*". I guess you mean a whole word that bound by [word bounderies](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `"\b$num\b"`

Comment: This is exactly what i mean, Thank you!\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using the roof sign before the variable...
But this pattern will eleminate wrong `123`

```
'08/25/2021 11:56:03 muzi.puzi 123 Bla
08/25/2021 19:56:03 bla.bla 1234 Bla
08/25/2021 19:56:03 abc.def 54 bla123' > file.txt

$BioMetric_Num = '123'

Get-Content .\file.txt | Select-String -Pattern " $BioMetric_Num "
```

So in your case, your current function should be able to work correctly using

`Get_User_Dates_From_DBFile ' 123 ' $Db_file`